# DJPlay: No sound coming out

Tags: 10.10, sound, jack

I installed JACK and **DJPlay** on Ubuntu 10.10, they seem to launch and connect fine.
Then I open audio files in DJPlay, and start playing them, the oscilloscopes start moving.

But **no sound comes out**.

I am a newbie so I left everything configured as default.
Maybe it is just that I don't know how to use DJPlay and there is just a button to press somewhere? In the screenshot, note how the levels are moving in the "mixer" window but no signal in the levels in the upper-right side of the screen, not sure what it means.
**Any idea?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and just now solved it. The solution isn't optimal and I will look for a cleaner one, but this may help you anyway. (I'm running Debian/Gnome, so if you're on Debian or Ubuntu I suspect this procedure will work - on other distros there may be some differences).

First, start JACK control BEFORE you start DJPlay. Wait for it to display 'Started' in the display window. (If it doesn't get this far, then you probably have a problem with JACK). After it has started, then start DJPlay. Then, go back to the JACK control and click on 'Connect'. On the 'Audio' tab you should see 'DJPlay' in the 'Readable Clients' list, and both 'DJPlay' and 'system' in the 'Writable Clients' list. Expand 'DJPlay' in the left list, and 'system' in the right list. In the left list, click on 'player_1_left', then in the right list click on an item - on my system they show up as 'playback_1', 'playback_2', etc.. Then click on the 'Connect' button. A line should appear between left and right lists. Repeating the process, connect 'player_2_left' to 'playback_1', then connect 'player_1_right' to 'playback_2', then 'player_2_right' to 'playback_2'. This should connect the left and right outputs of both DJPlay decks to the left and right inputs of your computer sound system. If you play something in DJPlay, you should now hear it.

There has to be a better, more automated way to do this; if I find it I'll try to post directions.

I don't have a real-time kernel so I can't use the real-time option. I hear some squeaks that indicate the sound processing isn't quite keeping up with its task, so I'm going to need a dedicated computer with an RT kernel to get this working properly. But before I set that up, I'm going to play a bit to see if DJPlay is worth the effort. Good luck getting your setup running!

Comment: I did exactly like you said and now it works great!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should configure JACK with qjackctl (which you seem to have installed)

You should uncheck "Realtime" as you probably don't have a realtime-enabled kernel.

You should also raise the "Frames/Period" as you're having some [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrun), as they're called. The red text in the status box is telling you that.

Getting sound to work might take some tinkering on your part. If you install a neat little program called [patchage](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/patchage) (using `apt-get` or Software Center)
 then you can see a visual representation of your audio system with JACK. If this DJPlay program is truly JACK-enabled it should be very easy to connect and disconnect audio pipelines with Patchage.

JACK is a very advanced piece of software but unfortunately integrates poorly with the default environment. It takes getting used to.

Comment: Cool I will try as soon as I can :-)